# SpriteKit 'pinned' property allows y-axis change in position

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a SpriteKit game in which balls bounce around, interacting with other objects.

One of those other objects is a spinner that should rotate around its center, but *NOT* change its x/y position. It should be stationary except for the rotation.

According to Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1520354-pinned), `node.physicsBody.pinned = true` should do exactly what I want, making it so that:

> "the node’s position is fixed relative to its parent. The node’s position cannot be changed by actions or physics forces. The node can freely rotate around its position in response to collisions or other forces."

However, that's not what's happening. **What's happening is that the spinner's y-axis position changes when a ball hits it squarely** -- briefly moving down and then popping back into the correct position.

My code for the spinner (please assume all variables are defined):

```
      for i in 0..<spinners.count {
            let spinnerNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)
            
            spinnerNode.position = CGPoint(x: spinners[i].minX, y: spinners[i].minY)
            
            spinnerNode.size = CGSize(width: spinners[i].width, height: spinners[i].height)
            
            spinnerNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: spinnerNode.texture!, size: CGSize(width: spinners[i].width, height: spinners[i].height))
            spinnerNode.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
            spinnerNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
            
            spinnerNode.physicsBody?.pinned = true
            
            addChild(spinnerNode)
        }
```

Why on earth is my spinner node moving vertically when a ball collides with it? Why isn't `.pinned` working as advertised?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What node is its parent, and is that moving?

Comment: Good question. Its parent is the scene itself, which is not moving, no.

Comment: As a test, maybe create a parent node, set isDynamic = false, add spinnerNode to that. Any difference? Alternatively, does moving the line 'spinnerNode.physicsBody?.pinned = true' below the 'addChild(spinnerNode)' make a difference? Sometimes the order matters when applying different properties.

Comment: @JohnL Unfortunately, neither of those options changed the behavior of the spinner node. Thank you, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by setting the spinner node's `mass` to a value slightly greater than that of the ball nodes.

```
node.physicsBody?.mass = 6.0
```